# Loading an edit to an answer removes most signs of a duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23915723/2846923) I was looking at was closed as a duplicate, and showed all the signs of a duplicate:

[image]

But when I clicked on the "load edit" bar, The "[duplicate]" in the title was the only remaining thing to show that the question was a duplicate:

[image]

Thinking that it was probably reopened, I refreshed the page, but then the duplicate notices came back. The answer got edited again, I loaded the edit, the notices went away. When I edited the question, part of it came back:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184642/why-does-the-questions-closed-status-disappear-when-clicking-to-load-a-new-edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237419/238586):

> Took a while to track down, but this is now fixed and will be with you in the next build.
>
> rev 2014.8.01.1737, meta rev 2014.8.01.2407